# How to clean and reinstall NPM and NodeJS on OpenSUSE Leap 15.2?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, opensuse, zypper

As root, I deleted some directories in /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib on my OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 linux server to cleanup some nodejs modules. I then uninstalled `nodejs` and `npm` using Zypper (`zypper remove nodejs npm`). I removed '.npm' directory in root's home dir. I did a `find` for 'node_modules' from / and did not find any. After that, I installed 'nodejs' and 'npm' (`zypper install nodejs npm`), which reported it successfully installed them. But when I do 'npm -v', it fails with `/usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`. I tried uninstall/reinstall these packages multiple times, but npm keeps failing with this error. I have the output below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
The following 2 recommended packages were automatically selected:
  nodejs12-devel npm12

4 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 11.1 MiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the operation, additional 48.0 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/v/...? shows all options] (y): y
Retrieving package nodejs-common-2.0-lp152.3.2.noarch                                                                          (1/4),   8.1 KiB (  230   B unpacked)
Retrieving: nodejs-common-2.0-lp152.3.2.noarch.rpm ...............................................................................................[done (5.2 KiB/s)]
Retrieving package nodejs12-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64                                                                         (2/4),   7.3 MiB ( 27.9 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: nodejs12-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64.rpm ..............................................................................................[done (6.2 MiB/s)]
Retrieving package nodejs12-devel-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64                                                                   (3/4), 170.5 KiB (802.1 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: nodejs12-devel-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64.rpm ........................................................................................[done (2.4 KiB/s)]
Retrieving package npm12-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64                                                                            (4/4),   3.6 MiB ( 19.3 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: npm12-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64.rpm .............................................................................................................[done]

Checking for file conflicts: .................................................................................................................................[done]
(1/4) Installing: nodejs-common-2.0-lp152.3.2.noarch .........................................................................................................[done]
(2/4) Installing: nodejs12-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64 ........................................................................................................[done]
Additional rpm output:
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/node12 to provide /usr/bin/node-default (node-default) in auto mode


(3/4) Installing: nodejs12-devel-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64 ..................................................................................................[done]
(4/4) Installing: npm12-12.18.2-lp152.3.3.1.x86_64 ...........................................................................................................[done]
Additional rpm output:
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/npm12 to provide /usr/bin/npm-default (npm-default) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/npx12 to provide /usr/bin/npx-default (npx-default) in auto mode


host1:/ # which npm
/usr/bin/npm
host1:/ # npm -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
host1:/ # which node
/usr/bin/node
host1:/ # node -v
v12.18.2
host1:/ #
```

Comment: I would install node using a version manager. This means you can install multiple versions side by side and switch between them with ease. It also negates certain permissions errors you might run into. Let me know if this is something you would consider and I'll post an answer outlining how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

try forcibly reinstalling node and npm packages. if i am not mistaken, you can do that by:

```sh
$ zypper in -f $(rpm -qa nodejs* --qf '%{NAME} ')
$ zypper in -f $(rpm -qa npm* --qf '%{NAME} ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf package_lock.json
```

in all the places they were installed (remember: npm installs these in any directory where you executed `npm install <module_name>`). `find` is a useful command on linux to track all those dirs. In addition, I had to delete `.npm` directories from all the users as well (not just the root). After doing these and then reinstalling nodejs and npm using `zypper` was successful. Nothing else worked for me. Good luck.